# Anylogic Custom Port

Tags: java, class, anylogic

I wanted to create a custom port to add some functions useful to my model, but I'm having some trouble creating the java class following the guide.
For instance, I'm following the "Custom port classes" guide from Anylogic help.
Creating a new class and compiling it I receive this error message:

"Description: Implicit super constructor Port<CustomData,CustomData>() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor. Location: CustomProject/CustomPort - Java Class"

What am I missing?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: you are, as the message tells you, not "explicitly invoking another constructor". Check which constructor exists in the parent class, and call that from within your constructor

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this:
in the CustomPort java class, I changed:

```
public CustomPort() {}
```

with this:

```
public CustomPort(Agent ao) {
    super(ao);
}
```